# Applet on Browser

Tags: applet

How I can use some functions that were declared on the applet class? i.e.

this is my class

```
public class hi extends JApplet{

public void HiThere(){
    System.out.println("Hi on Java Console");
}

}
```

and on my browser it's declared something like:

```
<applet.... name="HI" id="HI"  ......>Ooops!!!</applet>"
```

but when I tried to use the function there was a mistake, so how a can use the functions declared on my applet class?? Thanks!!!

Comment: Where do you want to use the function? From JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

First you should do this change to your code:

> public class HI extends JApplet {
>
> public HI() {System.out.println("Hi on Java Console");}
>
> }

When you have done that, and your browser still has an error, then post the exact error message here. Also you might want to look for a tutorial "programming Java applets getting started", since your code tells me, that you don't seem to know what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

In order to call your class methods from js you must declare the `<object>` in html specifying a `.jar` or `.class` with your compiled content, the package of the main class and some other parameters like in the follow example (object is for IE, and embed is for FF):

I suppose that you want to invoke the `hi.HiThere()` method as defined in your question.

```
<object
width="100" height="100" id="hi">
<param name = "code" value = "path.to.your.main.class.hi">
<param name = "archive" value = "jar location">
<param name = "mayscript" value = "true">
<param name = "scriptable" value = "true">
...
    <comment>
       <embed 
          code = "path.to.your.main.class.hi" 
          archive = "your jar location"
          scriptable = "true"
          width = "100" height = "100"
          name = "hi"
          ...
       </embed>
</comment>
</object>
```

Then from the js you can access you object through the `document` using the `id` attribute in `<object>` or `name` in `<embed>` in the sample case `document.hi`. With the follow code you can invoke the `HiThere();` method:

```
try{
   // ie, ff
   document.hi.HiThere();
}catch(Exception){
   // chrome, safari, opera
   document.hi[1].HiThere();
}
```

In order to execute with last java versions remember to meet the new java security requirements (manifest attributes http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/manifestindex.html, jar signature... ).

Answer (score 0):

You can call the applet methods in JavaScript:

To do this the applet should be launched from JavaScript, e.g.

```
<script src="https://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
    <script>
        var attributes = { id: 'mainApplet', code:  
'org.jazzteam.Example', archive: 'example.jar', width: 812, height:  
635};                 
        var parameters = {};         
        deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.7');                 
        function actionInApplet(url) {                         
            mainApplet.appletMethod(url);                 
        }
</script>
```

In this case the applet is launched from JavaScript with **id= 'mainApplet'**. In the applet there is **appletMethod()** method, which we want to call. To do this you need to call the method related to JavaScript object with id name. You can also pass parameters to the called methods, as demonstrated in this example.

Also it is necessary to know that the applet method called from JavaScript should be privileged. To do this you need to wrap the method code in the following "wrapper":

```
AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
    public Object run() {
        //method code
        return new Object();
    }
});
```

This information is taken from the article:
[Frequently Asked Questions during Java applet development](http://jazzteam.org/en/technical-articles/frequently-asked-questions-during-java-applet-development/)